# Data gets Truncated from database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I am designing a Window based application in C# using VS2010 and SqlServer2008-r2. I am

using a service Based Database(.mdf),in it there is a table having four fields, if i Store

data in the table and close the application  and re-run the application the data gets Lost.

Why so and how to get rid of it.

I am Using Following routine for saving

```
private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program.connection.Close();

            bool k = srchpreventry();

            try
            {
                if (k)
                {

                 string query = " update orderform set Enrolment_Expected = " + textBox2.Text + ", Stock_on_Hand=" + textBox3.Text + ", Number_Required = "+ textBox4.Text + " where Name = '" + textBox1.Text + "';";
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Program.connection);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Program.connection.Close();
            }


            else
            {
               // Program.connection.Open();

                string query = "insert into orderform(Name,Enrolment_Expected,Stock_on_Hand,Number_Required) values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', ' " + textBox3.Text + "',' " + textBox4.Text + "')";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Program.connection);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Program.connection.Close();
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ae)
        {
            string str = ae.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }

        finally
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            Program.connection.Close();
        }

    }    



public bool srchpreventry()
        {

            Program.connection.Open();

            string query = " Select name from orderform where Name = '" + textBox1.Text + "';";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Program.connection);

            SqlDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dtr.Read() == true)
            {
                dtr.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                dtr.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }



private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program.connection.Close();
            Program.connection.Open();



            string query = " Select * from orderform where Name = '"  + textBox1.Text + "';";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Program.connection);

            SqlDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dtr.Read() == true)
            {
                textBox2.Text = dtr[1].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dtr[2].ToString();//GetString(2);
               textBox4.Text = dtr[3].ToString();
            }

            else
            {
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox3.Text = "";
                textBox4.Text = "";

            }


        }



public static  SqlConnection connection = null;
       static string appath = Library_Records.Program.app_path;

string connectionstring = string.Format(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True", appath);

static string dbfiles = null;
        internal static string app_path
        {
            get { return dbfiles = "|Datadirectory|\\records.mdf"; }
        }


/*******************datagrid code********************/
Program.connection.Open();
                    string query = "select * from orderform";
                    SqlDataAdapter MyDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    MyDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, Program.connection);
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    MyDA.Fill(table);

                    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                    bSource.DataSource = table;

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of truncated data or show the code that stores and reads data? One possible cause is that you try to store strings in nvarchar/varchar/nchar/char fields that are smaller than the strings that you store (e.g. If you store "Hello" in a varchar(3) field you'll get the string "Hel" when you retrieve it).

Comment: @mortb data gets lost no data is left in the database when i restart the application

Comment: @mortb I have added the routine for saving process

Comment: Put some breakpoints into your code. Run it to see if the update and insert statements are hit.

Comment: I would suggest that you pute the connection into a "using" statement foreach query. Then you will be guaranteed that it is closed after the query has been run.

Comment: @mortb as long as application is running the data will remain there because it is showed in datagridview and crystal report

Comment: Also the query parameters should not just be appended to the SQL strings but transfered to the database using the SqlCommand.Parameters collection. Appending them to the strings leaves a securtiy hole for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Where is the code that fills the grid?

Comment: @mortb i have added the code for grid view

Comment: I cant see any *obvious* errors. Maybe if you have the possibility of connecting to a full scale SQL server to see if you get the same errors there... I haven't done that much development using the SQL Server express edition. It annoys me not beeing able to query it directly with Management studio.

Comment: @ mortb The value inserted into databse directly i.e. by right clicking database and then add new query remains in the database but the data which i enter through textbox and save sequence gets lost

Comment: @mortb The data is not getting updated in the table

Comment: have you *tried* setting some breakpoints to see if the update/insert statements really run and what the SQL looks like?

Comment: @mortb yeah i have added the breakpoints the statements are getting executed but data is not updated in the table.If required i can send you the code

Comment: I don't think more code would help. *Suggestion:* Try to isolate the problem by refining the scenario. Create a new aspx page that does three things inside Page_Load: 1. SELECT from the table wanted in the DB and display the results using Response.Write().  2. INSERT a new row into the same table. 3. SELECT again from the same table and display it again using Response.Write() Don't use any other code in you project. Add connection strings as constants in the page. The purpose is to test your database connectivity. If it doesn't work your database is probably set up wrongly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you can increase the characters allowed in the column for example nvarchar(max) cause now it could be nvarchar(200) - this is just an example

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio?

You are not by chane having VIsual Studio load the same empty database again every time you start debug?

> and close the application and re-run the application the data gets Lost.

Either someone ignores errors that get thrown on insert, does not commit a transaction or tvisal studio just ocpies the same rdatabase template into the directory every time you start.

Comment: The value inserted into databse directly i.e. by right clicking database and then add new query remains in the database but the data which i enter through textbox and save sequence gets lost

Answer (score -2):

I strongly (emphasis on *strongly*) suggest that you start using stored procedures (either in code or in the database), but besides that.. you don't start a transaction or something similar? 
Or post the Program.Connection class code into the question.

Comment: I would vote for using an ORM (Entity Framework or Fluent NHibernate) instead of stored procedures or inline SQL. IT is much faster to work that way. I would say don't use stored procdures unless you need them for preformance etc.

Comment: @mortb great said. The answer is off topic and shows a total lack of experience of how to work efficient. ORMs beat SP hands down in development time and are good enough 90% of the time.

Comment: Yeah, I've worked with stored procedures in T-Sql since 1999 and it takes *so much time and focus* from what you really want to do. What you want to do is build a domain model that is really easy to alter as needed. You don't want to spend about a 3rd of the development time thinking about how objects are stored. I am considering "erasing my memory banks" that contain stored procedure syntax ;)